# If statement to prompt a popup box when clicked

Tags: javascript, if-statement, alert

I am trying to create a popup whenever someone clicks on a button to alert "right answer" when btnthree == characterName but it seems not to be working. It alerts the else statement "no answer."

````
function nextItem() {
        index++; 
        index % arr.length;
        return arr[index];
      
      }   

      function prevItem() {
        index--;
        if (index < 0) index = arr.length - 1;
        return arr[index]
      }
      
      function optionTwo() { 
           if (btnThree == characterName) {
           alert("right answer"); 
         } else {
           alert("No answer");
          {window.location.reload()}
         }}

 const characterName = document.getElementById('character-name');
       characterName.textContent = nextItem();

 const btnThree = document.getElementById("btn-3");
       btnThree.textContent = nextItem();
       btnThree.addEventListener('click', optionTwo);

      btnTwo.addEventListener('click', optionTwo);
      document.getElementById("next-btn").addEventListener('click', function (e){
      characterName.textContent= nextItem();
      
      document.getElementById("next-btn").addEventListener('click', nextItem);
        });
      });```

Help please?
````

Comment: Have you tried using triple equals instead of double equals in the if-statement?

Comment: @humanshado yes I have, doesn't work

Comment: Do you have your if statement above where the variables are being created? It seems like you tried to fulfill the idea of the minimal amount of code requirement but in doing that you messed up the code provided and left some out.

Comment: @imvain2 sorry yes I've added more of the code that is relevant to the problem. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: characterName  and btnThree are objects of two different DOM elements, so they will never be equal. In your case, I hope, you want to compare the text contents.

Comment: @Dinash yep thanks, its just the text contents contained in the const. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. I needed to use .textContent/.innerText, when comparing the actual relevant text inside of them. For example BtnThree.textContent == characterName.textContent